# Java code explanation needed (recursive maze solver)

Tags: java, recursion

There might come some follow up questions for this (and yes this is homework), but we have to solve a maze in my Java programming class (complete beginner) with using a recursive method. Now my problem is not the actual solving (yet, I am sure it will soon be my problem), but the fact that we have been given a part of the code by the teacher and there is some stuff in it that I have absolutely no clue what it is, or what it means.

Yes, I could ask my teacher, but I really don't like this guy and I am really just trying to learn Java and get some college credit points.

```
public class MazeSolver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] mArr = {
            {2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0},
            {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0},
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3}
        };

        boolean result = solve(mArr, 0, 0); // i = 0, j = 0: Point of entry in the upper left corner
        String str = (result) ? "" : " nicht";
        System.out.println("Das Labyrinth ist" + str + " loesbar");
    }

        static boolean solve(int[][] mArr, int i, int j) {


        return false;
    }

        static void print(int[][] mArr) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int[] arr : mArr) {
            for (int n : arr) {
                System.out.print(n + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Ok, so my problem is this line: boolean result = solve(mArr, 0, 0); // i = 0, j = 0: Point of entry in the upper left corner .

I am assuming this means that result is the result of the method which I am still to define, but what is `(mArr, 0, 0)`? I am guessing that is supposed to give the location in the maze but I thought that a location in an array is i.e. `mArr [0][0]`. And how does the program know that 0 and 0 is i and j or is that something that I need to tell it at some point?

Comment: Could you clarify the meaning of 0s, 1s, 2s and 3s in the array?

Comment: I'm gonna guess 2 is the start, 3 is the end, and 1 is a possible space to move to

Comment: Then why would you specify the start position? In either case I don't think it changes the answer to OP's question

Comment: 'tis some kind of treasure map.

Comment: (mArr, 0, 0) are the arguments you are passing to the `solve` function.  mArr is the int[][], and the first 0 is `i` and the second 0 is `j`.  In this function, you will do `mArr[i][j]` to access that cell in the array.  You are right in assuming that you will need to pass these `i` and `j` arguments to the solve function each time

Comment: 2 is the start, 3 is the end, 1 is a free way, 0 is a wall . and thank you @holtc now that makes a little more sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve() calls the method you have defined `static boolean solve(int[][] mArr, int i, int j) {`. It passes the array, along with i and j to that method. i and j represent the start position. You are correct that the starting position would be mArr[i][j], so inside the solve method, do this.

i.e.

```
static boolean solve(int[][] mArr, int i, int j) {
    int startPosValue = mArr[i][j]
    //code to determine return value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you can only move right or down, as otherwise it's not possible to solve with those three arguments. Then, the algorithm will be:

```
static boolean solve(int[][] mArr, int i, int j) {
    if (mArr[i][j] == 3) {
        return true;
    } else {
    try {
        if (arr[i+1][j] == 1 &&solve(mArr, i+1, j))
            return true;
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {};
    try {
        if (arr[i][j+1] == 1 && solve(mArr, i, j+1))
            return true;
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {};
    return false;
}
```

It'll return `true` if there is existing path and `false` otherwise.

How it works?

The signature could be rewritten:

```
static boolean solve(int[][] mArr, int currentX, int currentY)
```

It checks if `mArr[i][j]` is 3 (end). If yes, it returns `true`. Otherwise it checks if there is a possibility to reach the end by moving right or down.

Comment: "Now my problem is not the actual solving (yet, I am sure it will soon be my problem)". Oh how wrong he was.

Comment: I was specifically not asking for the solution, just for an explanation, now I'll just hope that my teacher won't find this...

Comment: @ScotMatson it is recursive solution.

Comment: yep it does look recursive, @xenteros do you think simply return arr[i+1][j] == 1 &&solve(mArr, i+1, j) || arr[i][j+1] == 1 && solve(mArr, i, j+1); would work also?

Comment: It wouldn't in case exception is thrown in first half of the expression. You have to aware of IndexOutOfBoundsException. I used the Exception handling instead of comparing to array length

Comment: Oh dang, yeah, the formatting is just bad. It is recursive.